# Java Swing ghost/doubled components?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

(edit) This issue is resolved - see answer.

I'm running into an unfortunate issue with Java/Swing and Netbeans I've never seen before. I've designed a basic card game form in Netbeans, which appears to work just fine. Image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcZ7F.png

Note the navigator view in the bottom left, clearly listing all the components in the bottom panel.

When I actually run the game, it seems fine at first sight...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNKK8.png

...but when you maximize the window, you suddenly see a copy of the panel contents for no apparent reason.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0LhY.png

This overlap is not only confusing, it also causes button events to point to the *wrong components*, rendering the game completely unplayable. By default the correct text area for the chat is displayed, but when you click it to focus, it suddenly brings the empty text area to the front as well, effectively hiding the chat text area.

This issue affects the top panel as well, having dummy duplicates of jLabels that are supposed to have no text (seen on the right).

Whatever can be causing this and how can it be resolved? I can't find duplicates of the panel in the navigator, cleaning and building doesn't work, and even the auto-generated code shows no hints of ever adding two text areas to the window.

Help is greatly appreciated!

(edit) The relevant auto-generated initComponents code is below. I have never touched this code as it is auto-generated by Netbeans.

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel bC1;
private javax.swing.JLabel bC2;
private javax.swing.JLabel bC3;
private javax.swing.JLabel bC4;
private javax.swing.JLabel bC5;
private javax.swing.JLabel bC6;
private javax.swing.JLabel bC7;
private javax.swing.JSpinner betSpinner;
private javax.swing.JButton btnBet;
private javax.swing.JButton btnPass;
private javax.swing.JPanel gamePanel;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC3;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC4;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC5;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC6;
private javax.swing.JLabel lC7;
private javax.swing.JPanel playingField;
private javax.swing.JPanel plrBottom;
private javax.swing.JPanel plrLeft;
private javax.swing.JPanel plrRight;
private javax.swing.JPanel plrTop;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC1;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC2;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC3;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC4;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC5;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC6;
private javax.swing.JLabel rC7;
private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC1;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC2;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC3;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC4;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC5;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC6;
private javax.swing.JLabel tC7;
private javax.swing.JTextArea textAreaChat;
// End of variables declaration  

private void initComponents() {

    statusPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textAreaChat = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    betSpinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    btnBet = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnPass = new javax.swing.JButton();
    gamePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    plrRight = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    rC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    rC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    rC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    rC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    rC5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    rC6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    rC7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    plrBottom = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    bC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bC5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bC6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bC7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    plrLeft = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lC5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lC6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lC7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    plrTop = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    tC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tC5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tC6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tC7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    playingField = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 180));

    textAreaChat.setEditable(false);
    textAreaChat.setColumns(20);
    textAreaChat.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textAreaChat);

    jButton1.setText("Send");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Betting");

    btnBet.setText("Bet");
    btnBet.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnBetActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnPass.setText("Pass");
    btnPass.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnPassActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout statusPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(statusPanel);
    statusPanel.setLayout(statusPanelLayout);
    statusPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 308, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 389, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(btnBet, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(betSpinner, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(btnPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addContainerGap())))))
    );
    statusPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(betSpinner, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(btnBet)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(btnPass))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27))
    );

    getContentPane().add(statusPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    gamePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    rC1.setText("jLabel1");
    rC1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    rC2.setText("jLabel1");
    rC2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    rC3.setText("jLabel1");
    rC3.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC3.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    rC4.setText("jLabel1");
    rC4.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC4.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    rC5.setText("jLabel1");
    rC5.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC5.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    rC6.setText("jLabel1");
    rC6.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC6.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    rC7.setText("jLabel1");
    rC7.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC7.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    rC7.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout plrRightLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(plrRight);
    plrRight.setLayout(plrRightLayout);
    plrRightLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        plrRightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrRightLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(plrRightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(rC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    plrRightLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        plrRightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrRightLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(5, 5, 5)
            .addComponent(rC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(rC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(rC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(rC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(rC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(rC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(rC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    gamePanel.add(plrRight, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    bC1.setText("jLabel1");

    bC2.setText("jLabel1");

    bC3.setText("jLabel1");

    bC4.setText("jLabel1");

    bC5.setText("jLabel1");

    bC6.setText("jLabel1");

    bC7.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout plrBottomLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(plrBottom);
    plrBottom.setLayout(plrBottomLayout);
    plrBottomLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        plrBottomLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrBottomLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(bC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(bC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(bC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(bC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(bC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(bC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(bC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    plrBottomLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        plrBottomLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrBottomLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(bC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(bC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(bC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(bC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(bC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(bC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(bC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    gamePanel.add(plrBottom, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    lC1.setText("jLabel1");
    lC1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    lC2.setText("jLabel1");
    lC2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    lC3.setText("jLabel1");
    lC3.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC3.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    lC4.setText("jLabel1");
    lC4.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC4.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    lC5.setText("jLabel1");
    lC5.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC5.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    lC6.setText("jLabel1");
    lC6.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC6.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    lC7.setText("jLabel1");
    lC7.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC7.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));
    lC7.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(14, 34));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout plrLeftLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(plrLeft);
    plrLeft.setLayout(plrLeftLayout);
    plrLeftLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        plrLeftLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrLeftLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(plrLeftLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    plrLeftLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        plrLeftLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrLeftLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(5, 5, 5)
            .addComponent(lC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    gamePanel.add(plrLeft, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    tC1.setText("jLabel1");

    tC2.setText("jLabel1");

    tC3.setText("jLabel1");

    tC4.setText("jLabel1");

    tC5.setText("jLabel1");

    tC6.setText("jLabel1");

    tC7.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout plrTopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(plrTop);
    plrTop.setLayout(plrTopLayout);
    plrTopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        plrTopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrTopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addComponent(tC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    plrTopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        plrTopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(plrTopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(tC1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(tC2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(tC3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(tC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(tC5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(tC6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(tC7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    gamePanel.add(plrTop, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout playingFieldLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(playingField);
    playingField.setLayout(playingFieldLayout);
    playingFieldLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        playingFieldLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    playingFieldLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        playingFieldLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gamePanel.add(playingField, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(gamePanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for excluding it, editing it into the main post right now.

Comment: ..[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong by non-compilable non-runnable code. You are obviously using NetBeans generated code. Are you altering the code that per generated comments is not supposed to be altered? Are you overriding a component's `paint(Graphics g)` or `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method? I second @AndrewThompson's request for a [minimal compilable verifiable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm trying to verify it by creating an entirely new class, but it's been a while since I made a form in code, and it's proving to be a bit more difficult than expected. Again, I'm sorry for not properly following SE etiquette.

Comment: It's a hell of a lot easier if you use straight-forward layout managers and avoid using computer-generated layouts.

Comment: I've failed in actually getting the code to verify; duplicating the generated code and variables to a new class actually doesn't work in this case. If I can't even verify the code, should I close the question?

Answer (score 2):

I've located and resolved the issue; in the mess of the constructor, initComponents() was called twice. I am deeply ashamed.

Comment: Ah yes, hence my skepticism that *"The **relevant** auto-generated initComponents code is below."* and one more reason that I suggest an MCVE.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: Generally, a lot of inexplicable things come from places I would never think of looking twice, but the real shame is that this issue persisted for two days before it was actually located. However, the MCVE request is what lead me to finding it, so thanks for that!